# SSMS 'Debug' Output

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm having a problem with a TSQL query and narrowed it down to a problem with a SUBSTRING clause that fails. My problem is that there are roughly 500k rows in the table and I'm not sure how I can find the odd record that makes it fail.

Is there a way in SSMS to not just show "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" but the row/values of the record that is just processed?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please post your query, thanks.

Comment: If you are using CHARINDEX to look for a certain character, then substract 1 to get the substring before that character, you should consider the case when CHARINDEX returns 0 (when that character is not found). Usually I use NULLIF to handle this case.